# selecting list values depending on another select list values

Tags: vue.js

I have two select bar first for publisher and second for template so if i select publisher id=1 then it show only template which have publisher id=1

```
 <v-flex>
      @can('publish')
      @if (sizeof($publishers) > 1)
      <v-text-field type="hidden" style="display: none" v-model="publishers" name="publishers"></v-text-field>
      <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="publishers" :rules="[rules.required]" multiple chips persistent-hint>
      </v-select>
           <div class="text-danger">
               {{ $errors->first('publisher_id') }}
           </div>
           <v-text-field type="hidden" name="publisher_id" 
      </v-text-field>               
  </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter templates based on the currently selected publishers:

```
 <v-flex>
                @can('publish')
                @if (sizeof($publishers) > 1)
                <input type="hidden" :value="publishers" name="publishers">
                <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="publishers" :items="listPublishers" :rules="[rules.required]" multiple chips persistent-hint/>

                <div class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('publisher_id') }}</div>

                <v-select label="Templates" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="templates" :items="listTemplates.filter(tpl => (publishers || []).includes(tpl.publisher_id))" :rules="[rules.required]" multiple chips persistent-hint/>

                <input type="hidden" name="publisher_id">
            </v-flex>
```

Comment: but it working only for multiple publisher like this <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="publishers" :items="listPublishers" :rules="[rules.required]" multiple chips persistent-hint/> 

it dosent working for this if i remove multiple option from field <v-select label="Publishers" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="publishers" :items="listPublishers" :rules="[rules.required]" chips persistent-hint/>

Comment: For single publisher change the filter condition to `(tpl => tpl.publisher_id === selectedPublisher)`